# how do crop specific part of image based on the coordinate boxes?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I want to crop my image based on the coordinate boxes of  detected objects, the one with classID=1.

There might be multiple objects with the same id or other classes as well.
My problem is that my code only returns one cropped image, How could I return all cropped images with ClassID=1?

I have totall of 6 classes in which I am interested in ClassID=1.

```
  # initializing bounding boxes, confidences, and classIDs.
   boxes = []
   confidences = []
   classIDs = []

   for output in layersOutputs:
      # loop over each of the detections
      for detection in output:
         # extract the class ID and confidence 
         scores = detection[5:]
         classID = np.argmax(scores)
         confidence = scores[classID]

         # filter out weak predictions 
         if confidence > c_threshold:
            box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

            #coordinates 
            x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
            y = int(centerY - (height / 2))

            # update  bounding box coordinates, confidences, classIDs
            boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            classIDs.append(classID)

   # applying non maximum suppression
   ind = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, c_threshold, nms)

   if len(ind) > 0:
      # loop over the indexes that we want to keep
      for i in ind.flatten():
         # extract the bounding box coordinates
         (x, y) = (boxes[1][0], boxes[1][1])
         (w, h) = (boxes[1][2], boxes[1][3])



 for i in classIDs:
        if i != 1:
            continue
            # extract the bounding box coordinates
            (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
            (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
            # crop that part of image which contains desired object
        image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        cv.imshow("Image", image)

        path = '/path to folder'
        cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'PImage.jpg'), image)

        #
        cv.waitKey(0)
```

**Edited:** As you can see there are many types of animals in this picture, I am trying to crop part of image that has dogs in it. I already got the coordinate bounding boxes related to dog parts(which means that I know where is the location of the rectangle that has dog in it as indicated in the photo)

I want to crop those rectangles that I indicated in the image. Dog has class id=1. I have class cat and other animals with different indexes.

[image]

Comment: Please add a sample image and a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I edited the code and put image

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect.

```
classID= [1]
for i in classID:
```

Here you basically say `for i in [1]:`, which crops only for your first detection. Instead, you should loop over all detections. Assuming the rest of your code is correct, the following loops over all detections logged in `classID`, and only crops if it belongs to class 1.

```
for i in classID:
    if i!=1:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that as well,unfortunately, It still crops one of them.

Comment: Indentation for `(x, y)` and `(w, h)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are losing the reference to the original image in the following line.

```
image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

instead you can create new variable for each dog image

```
dog_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

Also while writing, you are writing by the same name, so it will overwrite the previous instance of the image, so try to make the name of the image to be dynamic like dog1.jpg, dog2.jpg ...

```
    c = 0
    for i in classIDs:
        if i != 1:
            continue
            # extract the bounding box coordinates
            (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
            (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
            # crop that part of image which contains desired object
        dog_img = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        cv.imshow("Image", dog_img )

        path = '/path to folder'
        c +=1
        cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'PImage'+str(c)+'.jpg'), dog_img )

        #
        cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: can you please  explain dynamic image output using code, my effort to solve this problem did not pay off.

Comment: I have edited the code, please accept the solution if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I did type print(type(classID)) it tells that

```
0
<class 'numpy.int64'>
1
<class 'numpy.int64'>
1
<class 'numpy.int64'>
0
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

As far as I know I can iterate on iterable objects, such as lists, single values such as int64 are not iterable.

How could I solve this problem?